# How do I calculate these expectations of the normal distribution?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have a question about the following exercice.

> Suppose that $X \sim N(1,2)$. (a) Find $E(X-1)^4$. (b) Find
> $E\left(X^4\right)$.
>
> Solution from text book: a. 12 b. 25

a) I have a different outcome that contradicts the textbook. Therefore I would like to know if my knowlegde is flawed. The expectation of a normal distribution is: $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mu$. Therefore, one could write $\mathbb{E}(X-1) = u$. The question would then be what is $u^4$.  The properties of expectation allow to write $\mathbb{E}(X1-1) = \mathbb{E}(X1)-1$. My calculation then would be $(1-1)^4$, which is zero and not 12

b) I am currently learning about moment generating functions and this would be my approach for solving this exercise. So I would differentiate this function: $e^{\mu t+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 t^2}$  four times and then set $t=0$. I found out that the 4th derivative of this moment generating function is very tedious to write out by hand. That made me wonder wheter I was using the correct approach. I computed the 4th derivative with the help of an online calculator to illustrate the large expression.

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^4}{\mathrm{~d} t^4}[\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{t})]=\boldsymbol{f}^{(4)}(t)=\left(\sigma^8 t^4+4 \mu \sigma^6 t^3+\left(6 \sigma^6+6 \mu^2 \sigma^4\right) t^2+\left(12 \mu \sigma^4+4 \mu^3 \sigma^2\right) t+3 \sigma^4+6 \mu^2 \sigma^2+\mu^4\right) \mathrm{e}^{\frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2}+\mu t}$

Could I please get feedback on this?

Comment: I think the book means $\mathbb{E}[(X-1)^4]$ and not $[\mathbb{E}(X-1)]^4$

Comment: I also think that moment generating functions will be extremely useful for both problems.

Comment: I see, could you please respond to point b?

Comment: I don’t see a better approach than what you’re doing in (b), but I haven’t taken the time to verify your computations. You should see some simplification. look here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments